# Dynamic Multiple Table View

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I planned to develop search app, where I want to build multiple tables in a single window where the values change dynamically.

Can anyone suggest a tutorial, source code, documents or links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think

This [sample code](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/TwoTableViews/) might help you...

After the insert value in tableView1/ tableView2  Please reload Data.

```
[tableView1 reloadData];
```

or

```
 [tableView2 reloadData];
```